# In a pattern matching partial function, how to make isDefined return false for invalid inputs that can't be included in the case pattern?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

In a partial function implemented with pattern matching, how to make `isDefined` return `false` for invalid inputs that can't be included in the case pattern?

For example, I have the following `decodeList` partial function:

```scala
case class Arr(items: List[Json]) extends Json
```

```scala
def decode(data: Json): Option[A]
```

```scala
def decodeList: PartialFunction[Json, List[A]] = {
  case Json.Arr(items) =>
    val options = items map decode
    if (options forall (_.isDefined)) options map (_.get)
    else throw new Error // the partial function should be undefined here
}
```

I want to change the code in a way so that `decodeList.isDefinedAt` evaluates to false for invalid inputs. For example, for an `a` that `decode(a)` evaluates to `None` ,`decodeList.isDefinedAt(Json.Arr(List(a)))` should evaluate to `false`.

Or from another perspective, if I try to include the condition in the case pattern as in the following code, where shall I put the `val options = items map decode` definition so it can be reusable by both the case pattern and the block?

```scala
def decodeList: PartialFunction[Json, List[A]] = {
  case Json.Arr(items) if (options forall (_.isDefined)) => 
   options map (_.get)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by defining a custom extractor object, e.g.

```
object Options {
  def unapply(items: List[Json]) = Some(items map decode)
}

def decodeList: PartialFunction[Json, List[A]] = {
  case Json.Arr(Options(options)) if (options forall (_.isDefined)) => 
   options map (_.get)
}
```

which isn't particularly convenient, but I don't know a better way.

Of course, I'd suggest actually defining `def decodeList(list: Json): Option[List[A]]` which fits better with `decode` and doesn't need such workarounds; then `Function.unlift(decodeList)` if you need a `PartialFunction`.

```
def decodeList(list: Json) = list match {
  case Json.Arr(items) => 
    val options = items map decode
    if (options forall (_.isDefined)) Some(options map (_.get)) else None
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Could you please also post a concise implementation of `def decodeList(list: Json): Option[List[A]]` for comparison?

Comment: Added it. There should be better ways to do it, but this one stays close to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you could override `isDefinedAt` by directly defining `PartialFunction` like so

```
def decodeList: PartialFunction[Json, List[A]] = new PartialFunction[Json, List[A]] {
  override def apply(json: Json): List[A] = json match {
    case Json.Arr(items) =>
      val options = items map decode
      options map (_.get)
  }

  override def isDefinedAt(json: Json): Boolean = json match {
    case Json.Arr(items) =>
      val options = items map decode
      options forall (_.isDefined)
  }
}
```

however this differs from the kind of `isDefinedAt` compiler would provide by [default](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#sec%3Apartial-functions).